# wrong-type-argument listp eval

Tags: directory-local-variables

I have a project which is centralized in a directory. The directory contains the `.dir-locals.el` file with the following content, just a defun:

```lisp
(defun pr--narrow-buffer ()
  "Narrow the current buffer from the start of the BODY section to the end of it."
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (setq v-beg (search-forward-regexp "^@BODY$"))
  (setq v-end (search-forward-regexp "^@/BODY$"))
  (narrow-to-region v-beg v-end))
```

When I open a file in that directory I get the error: `Error reading dir-locals: (wrong-type-argument listp defun)` and the `pr-narrow-buffer` function cannot be used.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A `.dir.locals.el` file is not supposed to contain arbitrary Lisp code, but a data structure resembling an alist where each key describes where to apply the settings to and the value which settings to apply.  The above function definition doesn't fit that pattern and therefore throws an error.  If there's no reason for that `.dir.locals.el` file to exist, just delete it and `M-x revert-buffer`.

Comment: Well, how can I store a set of function definitions, keybindings and other editor settings specific for a single directory/project?

Comment: You could use the `eval` keyword for that, but honestly, I'd just put them into a regular Emacs Lisp file and evaluate it from my Emacs config when needed.